# windows 8.1 computer keys not working

Tags: windows-8.1, keyboard, asus-laptop

Ok so the problem is that the seven and four keys is not working. im using a asus x202e (a laptop) and its the main keybroad. sticky keys, filter keys are off. the keybroad must be connected using a PC/AT adapter inside the laptop. the device name for this keybroad is:"PC/AT Enhanced PS/2 Keyboard (101/102-Key)" and its not working. I have a logitech adapter that connects to my mouse. stange thing is, that logitech adapter had installed some kind of logitech keybroad i didnt connect. and its right beside the PC/AT Enhanced PS/2 Keyboard (101/102-Key) keybroad. Here is a picture (Ignore the theme, just ignore.) [A picture screenshoted with snipping tool. hope this helps.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQMbk.png)

Comment: Have you tried an accessory (external) keyboard?  And does that work?

Comment: yes, could be the main keybroad?

Comment: I reinstalled the drievrs, and still the issue is going on